# How to show keyboard when entering key in searchbar in ios8

Tags: ios, swift

I have added a SearchBar in my TableView in my ios8 application. 
I would like to know why the keyboard does not show up when I click on the searchbar.

Attached is the screenshot, the table view is blurred out, but no keyboard is shown.

Comment: Have you checked the seachBar did become firstResponder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the simulator. In the iOS 8 simulator, the soft keyboard is hidden by default if you allow the simulator to access the mac's keyboard. You can toggle the appearance of the soft keyboard with Cmd + Shift + K. The relevant settings are in the Hardware menu.

Comment: Yes, I am using ios8 simulator. does that mean I don't need to set searchbar to become first responder (like in other people's answers?

Comment: @n179911 The other solutions are based on the first thing to try if you were experiencing this on a real device. Since that isn't the case, don't worry about it. When a text field (even in the search bar) is selected by the user, it becomes the first responder on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
Set searchbar.delegate = self;

```
-(void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my textField this issue was not coming before but This worked for me

iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard

Uncheck "Connect Hardware Keyboard"